# Magento default "Customer Groups"

Tags: php, magento, content-management-system

When adding a new product I would like it to be populated with all of my "customer groups".

This will be how the product is priced basically. A customer has to belong to a customer group to be able to purchase.

Does anybody have any advice of the best way of extending Magento to add customer groups by default?

Regards